# Duplicating a Ruby array of strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, copy, clone, dup

```
arr = ["red","green","yellow"]

arr2 = arr.clone
arr2[0].replace("blue")

puts arr.inspect
puts arr2.inspect
```

produces:

```
["blue", "green", "yellow"]
["blue", "green", "yellow"]
```

Is there anyway to do a deep copy of an array of strings, other than using Marshal as i understand that is a hack.

I could do:

```
arr2 = []
arr.each do |e|
  arr2 << e.clone
end
```

but it doesn't seem very elegant, or efficient.

Thanks

Comment: you can do shorter inline block: arr.each{|e| arr2 << e.dup}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your second solution can be shortened to `arr2 = arr.map do |e| e.dup end` (unless you actually need the behaviour of `clone`, it's recommended to use `dup` instead).

Other than that your two solutions are basically the standard solutions to perform a deep copy (though the second version is only one-level deep (i.e. if you use it on an array of arrays of strings, you can still mutate the strings)). There isn't really a nicer way.

Edit: Here's a recursive deep_dup method that works with arbitrarily nested arrays:

```
class Array
  def deep_dup
    map {|x| x.deep_dup}
  end
end

class Object
  def deep_dup
    dup
  end
end

class Numeric
  # We need this because number.dup throws an exception
  # We also need the same definition for Symbol, TrueClass and FalseClass
  def deep_dup
    self
  end
end
```

You might also want to define deep_dup for other containers (like Hash), otherwise you'll still get a shallow copy for those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sepp2k, so if you have a nested array, the only way is to use Marshal?

Comment: @Jon: No you could also define a recursive deep_dup method (see my edit), but using Marshal is usually easier.

Comment: Can't you avoid patching Numeric etc. by defining deep_dup in Object to do this?: respond_to?(:dup) ? dup : self

Comment: @Lars: No, because Numerics do respond to dup. They just respond by throwing an exception.

Comment: @sepp2k: Bummer. Then something like [Numeric, Symbol, TrueClass, FalseClass].include?(self.class) ? self : dup; ought to do the trick.

Comment: @LarsHaugseth: It does if you replace `include?(self.class)` with `any? {|c| self.is_a? c}` or if you add all of the subclasses of Numeric to the array.

Comment: There is a problem with DUP if your array has FixNums like integer - can't dup Fixnum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964143/why-dont-numbers-support-dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165957/ruby-cant-dup-fixnum

Comment: @stack1 That's why I defined `deep_dup` to return `self` rather than calling `dup` for numbers.

Answer (score 7):

I am in a similar situation and very concerned about speed. The fastest way for me was to make use of `map{&:clone}`

So try this:

```
pry(main)> a = (10000..1000000).to_a.shuffle.map(&:to_s)
pry(main)> Benchmark.ms { b = a.deep_dup }                                                                                     
=> 660.7760030310601
pry(main)> Benchmark.ms { b = a.join("--!--").split("--!--") }
=> 605.0828141160309
pry(main)> Benchmark.ms { b = a.map(&:clone) }
=> 450.8283680770546
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend your initial idea, but written slightly more concisely:

```
arr = ["red","green","yellow"]
arr2 = arr.inject([]) { |a,element| a << element.dup }
```

Comment: There is a problem with DUP if your array has FixNums like integer - can't dup Fixnum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964143/why-dont-numbers-support-dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165957/ruby-cant-dup-fixnum

Answer (score 3):

You can make a deep copy of array `a` by following code:

```
 Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks so simple.. Just run the below code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [].replace(a)

b[1] = 5

puts a
puts b
```

Run above code and you will notice the difference. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this hack:

```
arr1 = %w{ red green blue }
arr2 = arr1.join("--!--").split("--!--")
```

But it is just for fun :)

```
arr2[0].replace("lol")
p arr1
#=> ["red", "green", "blue"]
p arr2
#=> ["lol", "green", "blue"]
```

And it will work only for 1 level arrays

Comment: It will also only work if the array only contains strings and none of the strings contain "--!--" as a substring.

Comment: sepp2k, yeap, it's just hack for one purpose only :) like tetra pack