# ruby can't dup Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code like this

```
ssh_files = ["id_rsa.pub","id_rsa"]
ssh_files.each_with_index do |item, index|
      ssh_files[index] =  generate_ssh_path(creator).concat(item)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(ssh_files[index], 0770) unless File.exists?(generate_ssh_path(creator))
```

end
and I get this error message

```
TypeError (can't dup Fixnum):
  command.rb:45:in `block in generate_ssh_key'
  command.rb:42:in `each'
  command.rb:42:in `each_with_index'
```

Edit here's the stack

```
TypeError (can't dup Fixnum):
  command.rb:44:in `block in generate_ssh_key'
  command.rb:42:in `each'
  command.rb:42:in `each_with_index'
  command.rb:42:in `generate_ssh_key'
  key.rb:14:in `create_key'
  key.rb:10:in `initialize'
  app/models/user.rb:207:in `new'
  app/models/user.rb:207:in `ssh_key'
```

Comment: `ssh_files[file]` should be `ssh_files[index]` everywherel, and `|index,file|` should be `|file,index|`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I changed like you proposed I get now this message  TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
  command.rb:43:in `[]='

Comment: @user1611830 Humm I know.. naming convention just showing wrong impression..that's it. But the error is somewhere else..

Comment: @mbratch, I get now this message : TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
  command.rb:44:in `[]='

Comment: Did you change `|file,index|` as well? Please update your post with all your changes and the new error message so we can see what's going on.

Comment: In your code some where probably `Fixnum#dup` has been called.

Comment: @mbratch I changed accordingly to the edit of my post

Comment: show full error stack

Comment: The error in your post doesn't match the error you indicated in your comment. Which one is correct?

Comment: The error appears to be on the third line after the `each_with_index`.  You're only showing two lines after.

Comment: @mbratch the error is the  one I indicate now in my post

Comment: I can't even figure out what the question is.  This is normal behavior, as a Fixnum is an always the same object and it would make no sense to duplicate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options to `mkdir_p` are supposed to be a `Hash`, since it accepts a variety of options, so call it this way:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p(ssh_files[index], :mode => 0770)
```