# Filtering 2 dimensional array with no side-effects

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'd like to filter a 2 dimensional array taking the desired column indices and returning a 2d array with only those columns. Except on an empty array I'd like to return the same 2 dimensional array.

Also I don't want to modify the original array, and I'd like to write my code without any if statements, or limit branching as much as possible.

I'm wondering if it is redundant to `Marshal#load` and `Marshal#dump` and use `#map!`.

There reason I chose to use `#map!` is so I don't have to use an `if..else..end` block, but I'm curious to learn other strategies.

Below is my solution:

```
def keep_columns args
  matrix = Marshal.load Marshal.dump args[:matrix]
  columns = args[:columns]
  matrix.map! do |row|
    row.select.with_index { |_,idx| columns.include? idx }
  end unless columns.empty?
  matrix
end

matrix = [['foo','bar', 'baz'],['cats', 'and', 'dogs']]

keep_columns matrix: matrix, columns: [0,2]
#=> [["foo", "baz"], ["cats", "dogs"]]
keep_columns matrix: matrix, columns: []
#=> [["foo", "bar", "baz"], ["cats", "and", "dogs"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
matrix.map(&:dup)
```

This creates a copy of the matrix.

---

Pro tipp — Your code does a linear search over `columns` for each element in the innermost loop, maybe use `row.values_at(*columns)` instead?

```
def keep_columns(args)
  columns, matrix = args.values_at(:columns, :matrix)
  return matrix.map(&:dup) if columns.empty?
  matrix.map { |row| row.values_at(*columns) }
end
```

Comment: +1 for the pro tip, will upvote when I have my votes. Can you provide an example? Also, do you think your technique `matrix.dup.map(&:dup)` is applicable to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657091/use-replace-to-make-a-copy-of-an-array)?

Comment: That question has a 1D array only. For 2D arrays `matrix.map(&:dup)` is correct, your marshalling code would also clone the elements of the matrix which you sure don't want to happen.

Comment: Thank you @akuhn! Can you please change `(columns)` to `(*columns)`? :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) before and after [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at).

```
def extract_columns(arr, columns)
  return arr if columns.empty?
  arr.transpose.values_at(*columns).transpose
end

arr = [['foo','bar', 'baz'],['cats', 'and', 'dogs']]

extract_columns(arr, [0, 2])
  #=> [["foo", "baz"], ["cats", "dogs"]] 
extract_columns(arr, [])
  #=> [["foo", "bar", "baz"], ["cats", "and", "dogs"]]
```

Note that `arr` is not modified.