# CSV Data Import To MYSQL DB Using RUBY

Tags: ruby, csv, mysqlimport

I am trying to insert data via csv to database.
This is my controller code

```
    require 'csv'
      def index

      end

      def add
        @filename=CSV::Reader.parse(params[:dump][:file])
        n=0
        CSV::foreach(@filename, :headers => true) do |row|
        Student.new(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys).save
        n=n+1
        end
        flash.now[:message]="CSV Import Successful,  #{n} new records added to data base"
      end
```

Now when i am inserting a csv file i am getting the error

```
**can't convert CSV::IOReader into String**
```

My ruby version is 1.8.7

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ruby, you could use the following code:

```
require 'csv'

def index

end

def add
  n=0
  CSV::foreach(params[:dump][:file]) do |row|
    Student.new(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys).save
    n=n+1
  end
  flash.now[:message]="CSV Import Successful,  #{n} new records added to data base"
end
```

You can get more information about CSV:foreach on http://apidock.com/ruby/CSV

---

I failed with the above reply because I assumed that the [:dump][:file] was the path to the file (string object), but seeing that error, you should read the file first (it is a TempFile object), and then parse the content as string:

```
require 'csv'
  def index

  end

  def add
    n=0
    CSV::parse(params[:dump][:file].read, :headers => true) do |row|
      Student.new(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys).save
      n=n+1
    end

    flash.now[:message]="CSV Import Successful,  #{n} new records added to data base"
  end
```

Comment: thankyou for this but now m getting this error :-
**can't convert Tempfile into String**

Comment: Okk dis works out... but i am stuck on something new.. **uninitialized constant DataImportController::Student** I guess its the issue with routing.. can you provide the code for that..

Comment: I got this rectified.. but when i am adding the data , it says **can't dup Fixnum** any idea about this/?

Comment: You can check that links:

[Numeric.dupicable](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Numeric/duplicable%3F)

and 
[Why don't numbers support .dup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964143/why-dont-numbers-support-dup)

Comment: i did not understand this. Does this mean i have duplicate data in my csv..?

Comment: That problem is that some code on the Student.new(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys).save sentence is using someNumber.dup to get a copy of that number. Make sense?

Comment: yes.. i got that. I modified the code now.. Things go well.. But i am still facing an issue. Please check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110300/error-while-importing-csv-document-0-records-get-added