# Fix value in lambda

Tags: ruby, lambda, scope

I want to use a variable in a lambda, and have the resulting `Proc` retain that value as if it were a constant.

If I do the following

```
x = 5
f = lambda {x}
x = 4
f.call
```

I get 4. How I construct a lambda (or Proc object, or something similar) so that it always returns what `x` was at the time of its construction, regardless of the value of `x` at the time at which it was called?

I have a (potentially large) set of dynamically generated classes, and I want each one to have a different value for a certain constant (the hostname of a connected client, FWIW). For reasons beyond my control, I am forced to stick with the many-subclasses architecture--I can not modify the code so that the various hostnames are passed in as parameters to a constructor.

Comment: Do you really need it to be a lambda?

Comment: I need to be able to use it in a monkey patch in code: `myclass.class_eval {define_method: :new_method, maybe_lambda_expression}`

Comment: @AndrewCone Can you explain what you're actually trying to do, in real, non-hypothetical, non-redacted terms?

Comment: My terms are real and neither redacted nor hypothetical. What further non-hypothetical information would be helpful?

Comment: Actual code where it is to be used, with actual context.

Comment: I'm not trolling, I simply believe you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/13). It is the responsibility of answerers to rat out XY problems early, to help find the best solution approach.

Comment: Why do I believe you have XY problem? Because you started mentioning monkey patching with `class_eval`, when you didn't state this in the original question. This is _relevant_ information (and you are still withholding information on where and how your monkey patching is being used), and it is counterproductive to hide it.

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the question to include information about the purpose of the monkey patching.

Comment: @AndrewCone Thanks for the update. I've updated my answer in a way that hopefully matches better what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you might do hostname tagging within a single function:

```
def tag_hostname(obj, hostname)
  obj.singleton_class.class_exec(hostname) do |hostname|
    define_method :hostname, -> { hostname }
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
Foo = Class.new
Bar = Class.new
tag_hostname Foo, 'foo.example.com'
tag_hostname Bar, 'bar.example.com'
Foo.hostname   # => 'foo.example.com'
Bar.hostname   # => 'bar.example.com'
```

Or perhaps you're trying to work with `Foo::HOSTNAME` instead? Then it's even easier, just use `Module#const_set`.

---

To answer the original question, you can bind the `x` to a function scope. Like so:

```
def constantly(x)
  ->(*) { x }
end
```

Example usage:

```
> a = constantly(42)
> a.call
=> 42
> a.call(1, 2, 3)
=> 42
```

(By the way, the name [`constantly`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons_1.htm) is from Common Lisp.)

Comment: Nice, is there a way to do this without `def`? If possible, I'd like to do it as code within a single function.

Comment: @AndrewCone See my answer if you're only able to use lambdas.

Comment: Thanks. Lambdas are preferable in my case, but the solution in this answer is instructive as well.

Comment: @AndrewCone It is much more reliable and preferred to use this answer, I must say again that my solution is hackish and not very mantainable, also it's not too readable, make sure to explain its calls if you're writing this code for anyone else (company or public).

Comment: Got it, using Chris's. Thanks!

Comment: Worried about accepted answer was replaced with quite different content, unrelated to the OP's question.

Comment: @DavidUnric It's not unrelated at all. I'm simply answering the actual question the OP has, after the additional information from the OP. Read the last update on the question, re what the OP is actually doing. I'm not averse to restoring the original content below the current content, if that alleviates your "worry".

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young ok, didn't see the answer before an update

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to accomplish this with only one call and a lambda, but it may be possible with two calls and still a single lambda:

```
x = 1
f = lambda {
    #first call binds value of x to internal variable of lambda
    @x = x if @x.nil? 
    return @x
}
puts f.call #binds x to lambda return
x = 2

puts f.call #returns the original x
```

If your actual lambda is more complex than simply returning x, you might want to wrap the actual code in a `if !@x.nil?`, so it doesn't get called the first time.

I would recommend Chris Hester-Young's answer, though, unless you can only use lambdas for any reason.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong. Your `@x` defined in lambda *is not its internal* variable but instance variable of current object referenced by `self`. Just try to print or overwrite `@x` after the first `f.call` to check yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The variable inside lambda changes because it's in the same scope as its definition and assignments.
You would need to *enclose* it as an upvalue inside a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

To use your example the code may look like:

```
x = 5
f = proc {|arg=x| lambda {arg}}.call
# created outer scope with proc and `catched' x value in arg
# inner lambda as a closure as a result of #call is assigned to f
x = 4
p f.call  # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I must ask why you want a lambda here. A lambda is designed to evaluate code when it is called. So if you set a lambda to evaluate x as you are here, then that means you want the value of x whenever you call the lambda. So if you change x before calling f, then by its nature the lambda is going to do exactly what you don't want it to do.

Having said that, my first inclination was to use #dup, but #dup doesn't work on immediates (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964244/1322783)). Not sure if you were actually using numbers here, or if you were using this as a simplified example. Although after working through this with strings, #dup still won't work because it isn't going to dup the string until after the string's reference has changed.

Which brings me to point 3. Part of what is going on here is when you set a variable in Ruby (and most programming languages), it is creating a reference to that variable's address in memory, not the value of the variable. So when you say `f = lambda {x}`, what that really means is "when I call `f.call`, I want it to go to where x is stored in memory and return whatever is there."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Edited the question to include the possibility that what I need is not a lambda